# Gsuite mail set up for vtiger mail manager

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

Trying to setup gsuite custom domain mail in vtiger mail manager. It shows authentication error(wrong credentials) but credentials are corrent. Mail manager works fine with normal gmail id.

Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)

Help me to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Comment: Thank you. No  coding work,  just mail setup with server name, username and password. works fine normal gmail id but authentication error gsuite custom domain email id like admin@example.com